# Linking a "Table view Controller" in storyboard to load an .xib?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I am making a Table View Controller based iOS app with over 100 cells.
That would be hard to navigate in Storyboard, so is there a way I can link a Table View cell to open an .xib file and then have a "Back" button in the .xib file to link back to storyboard?

I made an empty application to use with storyboards, please help.

Comment: You may want to check out [this previously asked question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701873/use-storyboards-combined-with-xib-file-iphone 

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is stoppin you from loading the XIB in code manually. The event `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is still there.