# How to use MainStoryBoard to load and change UIViewController [IOS]

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xib, nib

I think many developer have tried this, how to make `MainStoryBoard` to load many `UIViewController` with xib or use NIB method, there is the explaination :

1. I have one `MainStoryBoard` and connected with class ViewController that use `UIViewController`
2. I have `LoginViewController`, `HomeViewController` also each .xib file
3. The problem is i want separate each logical code at each controller but i addSubview to `MainStoryBoard` exp: `LoginViewController.xib` the logical at `LoginViewController.swift` from there i want got to `HomeViewController` when loged in ...can anyone solve that's problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode Storyboard and xib connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567833/xcode-storyboard-and-xib-connection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the **initWithCoder** method in the object-c class.

```
     if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
        [self addSubview:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

For more detail follow this link

[Add subview from a xib or another scene with storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11444019/4910767)

Comment: thanks @Badal Shah, sorry if my question is too nob,, i'm newbie for ios and swift ...

Comment: It's ok. no problem please mark as right answer if it helpful to you.