# Segues not working programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I migrated a project from using XIB's to Storyboard, according to these instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9708723/2604030
It went good.
But I can't make the segues work programmatically, and I need to use them this way, because I have 2 buttons that link to the same ViewController, with different types, hope you understand why from this image.

[image]
There are 2 difficulty mode buttons. The code I use:

```
`- (IBAction)btnNormalAct:(id)sender {
    LevelController *wc = [[LevelController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LevelController" type:0];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:wc animated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)btnTimedAct:(id)sender {
    LevelController *wc = [[LevelController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LevelController" type:1];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:wc animated:YES];
}`
```

This worked when I used XIB's, and I am sure I linked everything correctly in the storyboard's VCs. The seagues works if I make them from the storyboard. But how can I manage this situation.

**ALSO:** are those lines good when changing from XIB's to Storyboard? Is that the right way to do this change (the way shown in the link above)?

```
    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `PrepareForSegue` method to set things on the incoming view controller before it is called:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        LevelController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [vc setType:1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like charm ! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: And if you want to fire off the segue in code use: performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the button actions. Connect the segues to the buttons and give the segues unique identifiers. Then implement `prepareForSegue:sender:` in your controller. When the method fires, check the seque identifier and set the appropriate type on the `destinationViewController'.

When using a storyboard you should instantiate your controllers from the storyboard rather than using `initWithNibName:bundle:`. This is done by giving each view controller a unique identifier and then calling `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` (or, for the initial view controller, just `instantiateInitialViewController`) on the storyboard which you can get from the current controller (or if required with `storyboardWithName:bundle:`).

Comment: Thank you ! Can you explain me how to instantiate controllers from the storyboard, please ?

Comment: @Sebyddd You can set the class on the right-hand pane to your controller within the storyboard, I don't have XCode open to give you the specific name of the tab, but one of them let's you pick which controller to use.

Comment: I find that out. I tried this: http://i.cubeupload.com/tQZjPL.png but i get that error...