# How to add ADAL Storyboard files to an existing iOS app that uses Xibs

Tags: objective-c, iphone, azure, ios8, adal

I have implemented an iOS application and used xibs in that app. Now I want to integrate ADAL (Azure Active Directory Authentication Library) in my app, but the ADAL library has two storyboard files where they will redirect our application to their login page. My question is Do I need to change my app into Storyboard or Can I manage with both xib's and storyboards in my application? or Is there any way to change their Storyboard files to xibs?. Please help me.

Comment: @Brandon Werner, Can you please have a look on above question?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to convert your xib to storyboards. Both can co-exist in a single application. Here is the link that explains it. [Use storyboards in a project which has .xib files- iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701873/use-storyboards-in-a-project-which-has-xib-files-iphone)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.